# jQuery Shopping Cart animation plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I love the [Fly to Basket](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/fly-to-basket-effect-with-jquery/) jQuery plugin, and am looking for similar plugins.

If anyone knows of any plugins or sites using some different type of effect for a shopping cart, could you share that link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to your link: [sliding shopping cart](http://webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/file/jbasket/sliding-basket/)

Not jquery, but pretty slick: [simpleCart](http://demo.simplecartjs.com/)

Comment: This simple cart look fine, but i thing its taking some mcch time for loading images, but i like this simplecart ...is there any one doing such thing in shopping cart..

Comment: What do you mean "in shopping cart"?